# React-router-dom - default id to url /0/home or /1/home

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a quick question about `react-router-dom`. I have used it now for a while but I want to take it a bit further than the usually route system. The thing what I want to do is create an id before routes.

Let me explain it a bit better. I have an application with a logged in user. That logged in user can create multiple teams. What I want to do is to put the id of the team in the url. So you will get `/1/homepage (/:teamId/homepage)`. With this method I can create a button in the navbar for example to switch to another team and that will load all the data from that team.

Does anyone know how I can put the `teamId` as a default route before the specific route?

**Edit:**

```
export default function Router() {
    return (
        <Switch>
             <Route
                path="/1"
                render={({ match: { url } }) => (
                <>
                    <Route exact path={`${url}/`}><Redirect to={`${url}/home`}/></Route>
                    <Route exact path={`${url}/home`} component={Home} />
                    <Route exact path={`${url}/teams`} component={TeamsList} />
                </>
                )}
            />
            <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
            <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
        </Switch>
    )
}
```

Comment: What is the specific route? Can you include a more comprehensive code example of your `Router` and routes? [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Question not clear. You want `/:teamId` and `/:teamId/homepage` as separate routes? You want `/:teamId` to redirect to `/:teamId/homepage`? You want a default number for `teamId`? Something else?

Comment: Sorry for the bad description. I don't really know how to explain it. What I am trying to make is. I want to have the ```teamId``` To be always infront of the route that loads the component. So /:teamId/homepage or /:teamId/contact or /:teamId/settings. Etc. I want to do this because the user doesn't always need to first click on their team. It is just default. Hard to explain. An example https://imgur.com/GIKDeyr or https://imgur.com/mG8v30i. Here you can see depending on which account you are logged in it will put the id in the url

Comment: In both those examples it seems the unique id is *after* the main domain, i.e. who's calendar? `/calendar/123`, or `/calendar/456`. This is the more idiomatic way to organize your routes. Can you include your routing code in your question so we may see what you are working with and what/where you are trying to add these new routes?

Comment: I added the code what I have so far. Note that ```path="/1"``` is the teamid and that will be dynamic but this is just for testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will likely need to render the nested routes within another `Switch` component, and since the `Switch` won't be able to differentiate between a "/1/..." dynamic path and the other "/login" or "/register" paths you want to try and match them first.

```
export default function Router() {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
      <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
      <Route
        path="/:teamId"
        render={({ match: { url } }) => (
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path={`${url}/home`} component={Home} />
            <Route exact path={`${url}/teams`} component={TeamsList} />
            <Redirect to={`${url}/home`}/>
          </Switch>
        )}
      />    
    </Switch>
  )
}
```

## Demo

[image: Edit react-router-dom-default-id-to-url-0-home-or-1-home]

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried it out and it is working but I have two questions. 1. How can I redirect the root route (/) always to ```/:teamId/home```? 2. Do I need to always make my Links like this? ```<Link to="/:teamId/home">Home</Link>```

Comment: @Raccoon If you want to redirect from "/" to "/:teamId/home" the issue here is you need an absolute/specific `teamId` to use in the path. The `teamId` can be anything (other than the other specific roots you handle above it in the router), so your `Home` component needs to be robust enough to handle possibly invalid team ids. `<Redirect to="/0" />` would bounce a user into the nested `Switch` where the other redirect would bounce them to the nested homepage. I added this to the linked sandbox.

Comment: @Raccoon For the links, again, the `teamId` needs to be something specific, i.e. `<Link to="/1234/home">Team 1234</Link>`, but since these are dynamic you are likely fetching this as a list to display, so maybe you are mapping an array of team ids to links, something like `<Link to={\`/${teamId}/home\`>Team {teamId}</Link>`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I think I have an idea how I will do this now.